# How can I evaluate $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-(x+a/x)}}{x+b} dx$?

Tags: improper-integrals, bessel-functions

If $b=0$, then it reduces to $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-(x+a/x)}}{x} dx$, which is $2K_0(2\sqrt{a})$, where $K_0(x)$ is the zero-order modified Bessel function of the second kind.

However, if $b\neq0$, I do not know how to evaluate the integral or relate it to $K_n(x)$ or some other known function. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: My version of Mathematica finds no nice forms. I suspect you won't either.